# Highcharts Heatmap issue behind title text with alternateGridColor when using setOptions

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I'm having an issue when using setOptions with Highcharts heatmaps.
Using highcharts' own example fiddle, adding some code to set the alternate grid colour causes the colour to appear behind the title text;

[image: Heat map alternateGridColor title issue]

```
Highcharts.theme = {
    yAxis: {
        alternateGridColor: '#EEEEEE'
    }
};

// Apply the theme
var HighchartsOptions = Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattscotty/m56z3gtt/1/

This issue does not occur when setting the colour in the chart settings directly and overriding the colour in the chart settings, does not remove or override the issue.

We have mainly encountered this issue because we have one central function which sets the themes for our many different types of charts.
However, on adding a new heatmap option, I have encountered this issue.

Comment: You can set alternateGridColor: 'transparent' in your colorAxis, it should help you with your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/tpo8n3bL/1/

Comment: Grzegorz, thanks for the response, that does appear to be a workaround for the issue. Thanks

Comment: I have also added it as a bug to Highcharts github, you can find it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5569